# get-user - select users that were created before some date

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm using Quest snapin to get users from active directory. This script displays date and time, when users were created. The format is '07/16/2007 12:03:55'.

```
Get-QADUser -IncludeAllProperties -SerializeValues | Foreach-Object {$_.createTimeStamp}
```

How to display users that were created before 01/06/2011 00:00:00 ? Thank you!

Thank you. I have one more question. How to separate service accounts from domain users? I recognize, that every domain user has mail parameter. Is it possible to include only domain users?

```
(Get-QADUser user -includeallproperties -serializevalues).mail
user@company.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
Get-QADUser -IncludeAllProperties -SerializeValues -createdbefore 01/06/2011
```

If you want specify a date and time:

```
Get-QADUser -IncludeAllProperties -SerializeValues -createdbefore ([datetime]::parse("01/06/2011 01:00:00 pm")) # or "01/06/2011 13:00:00"
```

For the secon question try:

```
Get-QADUser user -includeallproperties -serializevalues | ? { $_.mail -ne $null } # or just {$_.mail}
```

Comment: thank you, christian. I updated my question. Can you please try to give me some advice how to separate domain users in the output? Thank you

Comment: @culter. I've edited my answer but next time is better for you to create a new question! Remeber to mark it as the answer if solve your problems..

Comment: (Get-QADUser -SerializeValues -IncludeAllProperties -CreatedBefore ([datetime]::parse("07/01/2011 00:01:00")) | ? {$_.mail -ne $null} | Select sAMAccountName, CreateTimeStamp, mail).Count

Comment: I used the one-liner above to count users created before specific date and have mail address. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The following is just using Powershell operator **lt**

```
Get-QADUser -IncludeAllProperties -SerializeValues | ? { $_.createTimeStamp -lt '01/06/2011' }
```

This should answer the extended question, it's just a matter of extending the filter. Try, for example, by adding a match on the mail value. Fo example if you know that the mail property is empty for the unwanted users:

```
Get-QADUser -IncludeAllProperties -SerializeValues | ? { ($_.createTimeStamp -lt '01/06/2011') -and ($_.mail -ne '')}
```

Comment: Thank you, empo. I have one more question. How to separate service accounts from domain users? I recognize, that every domain user has mail parameter. Is it possible to include only domain users? I updated my question. Thank you

Comment: Empo, this doesn't work for me. Doesn't matter which date I enter, this script don't consider that and still displays users created after this date.